# angular service promises and lodash creating empty objects

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I'm hoping this is just a stupid thing I'm overlooking or not doing correctly because it's killing me.

This is a portion of an angular controller that is polling the database (Parse) for a group of sales reps based on a known manager ID.

The first section checks for manager status and returns the group memberId's.

Then there is another check for additional group members based on the resulting memberId's. So there is a top level manager with a group of managerId's, and each of them have sales rep id's in a child group.

Everything here checks out (it may not be the most efficient way of getting there, but it works... for now - some day when I'm not writing the entire app solo I'll redo it).

Note... the LoggingService is just a fancy console.log output.

The problem is in the last promise return variable... managerGroup.

The output of the final LoggingService.info('-> managerGroup', managerGroup)(); is correct and it's also the output to $scope.pageData. As follows:

```
Object
  managerId:  "sL0lGF3sYw"
  groupMembers: Array [2]
    0: Object
      managerId:  "fytsi64nkp"
      salesGroup: false
    1: Object
      managerId:  "gcMIA9xnn0"
      salesGroup: Array [3]
        0:  "6MunY0xGvp"
        1:  "9O4ly8Coyw"
        2:  "K67ZSUsE0q"
```

Here's the part that has been wracking my brain. If I run a log on managerGroup.groupMembers the result is:

```
["fytsi64nkp", "gcMIA9xnn0"]
```

Maybe it's my code, maybe I'm missing something.

```
var ClientAccess    = Parse.Object.extend('ClientAccessLU');
    var query           = new Parse.Query(ClientAccess);

    query.equalTo('managerId', userId);

    query.first().then(function(results) {
        // check for manager status
        if (results) {
            LoggingService.info('user is manager', results)();
            $rootScope.managerFlag = true;
            // returns the current user managerID and group members
            return results.attributes;
        } else {
            LoggingService.warn('user is not a manager')();
            $rootScope.managerFlag = false;
            return false;
        }
    }).then(function(managerData) {
        // create a default managerGroup
        var managerGroup = {
            'managerId': managerData.managerId,
            'groupMembers': managerData.salesRepIds
        };

        // check if members are managers of additional groups and build the inner group
        lodash.each(managerGroup.groupMembers, function(member, index){
            UserLU.getGroupMembers(member).then(function(innerGroup){
                // add the innerGroup member id's to the main group
                managerGroup.groupMembers[index] = {
                    'managerId': member,
                    'salesGroup': innerGroup.salesRepIds?innerGroup.salesRepIds:false
                };
            });
        });
        return managerGroup;
    }).then(function(managerGroup){
        // then check the innermost group for client sales data as these members are sales reps
        LoggingService.info('-> managerGroup', managerGroup)();



        $scope.pageData = managerGroup;
    });
```

Any help is appreciated... thanks.

Comment: `managerGroup.groupMembers` is array or object ?

Comment: @kiro112 it is an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Promise` instead of `lodash.each`

```
Promise.all(managerGroup.groupMembers, function (member, index) {
    return UserLU.getGroupMembers(member)
        .then(function(innerGroup){
            // add the innerGroup member id's to the main group
            return member = {
                'managerId': member,
                'salesGroup': innerGroup.salesRepIds?innerGroup.salesRepIds:false
            };
        }); 
}).then(function (managerGroupMembers) {
    managerGroup.groupMembers = managerGroupMembers;

    return managerGroup;
});
```

Comment: I like the idea but I don't think it will work as is... the lodash bit was running inside a promise chain already - Promise.all shouldn't be thenable. Maybe I'm overcomplicating it. But I want to limit my nesting of chained promises.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct even though it doesn't work with my code because this is a chained promise inside another chained promise and it just doesn't work... but, you definitely alerted me as to why I'm getting the response I'm getting, so with that it's a solution. I just need to rewrite my code for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

As per what I had reviewed, for managerGroup.groupMembers log you are getting the output of

```
 var managerGroup = {
            'managerId': managerData.managerId,
            'groupMembers': managerData.salesRepIds
        };
```

as the below code run in async you are going to next then before you complete this code.

```
lodash.each(managerGroup.groupMembers, function(member, index){
            UserLU.getGroupMembers(member).then(function(innerGroup){
                // add the innerGroup member id's to the main group
                managerGroup.groupMembers[index] = {
                    'managerId': member,
                    'salesGroup': innerGroup.salesRepIds?innerGroup.salesRepIds:false
                };
            });
        });
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: I'm moving onto the next promise before lodash has had time to return - that's why @kiro112 suggests using Promise... this makes sense.